# Actionscript: Stage width is lesser than provided embed sizes and StageVideo.videoWidth

Tags: actionscript

How is that possible. How stage can be lesser than provided embed width and height in html embed costructor?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
    var swfVersionStr = "${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision}";
    // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
    var xiSwfUrlStr = "${expressInstallSwf}";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "${application}";
    attributes.name = "${application}";
    attributes.align = "middle";
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "${swf}.swf", "flashContent"
        ,"640", "360"
        ,swfVersionStr
        ,xiSwfUrlStr
        // flashvars
        ,{}
        // Params
        ,{
            wmode:'direct'
            ,quality:'high'
            ,bgcolor:'#ffffff'
            ,allowscriptaccess:'always'
            ,allowfullscreen:'true'
            ,allownetworking:'all'
        }
        ,attributes
    );
</script>
```

Actionscript part:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
private function onFrame(event:Event):void 
{
    log('stage width,height',stage.width,stage.height,sv.videoWidth,sv.videoHeight);
}
```

Output:

```
stage width,height 320 276 720 404
```

How to make stage fullscreen?

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the size set in the embed, you want [stage.stageWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageWidth) and stage.stageHeight.

As for all DisplayObjects, .width and .height tells the size of the content. So an empty stage would have a width and height of zero, regardless of what size the Flash Player was given in the embed code.

In other words, `stage.stageWidth` is the width of the Flash Player, while `stage.width` is the width of the stuff added to the stage.

Comment: At last! What i wanted to hear. Thank you! :)
It's now makes sense to what was happening yesterday.

Comment: One last question. Why stage.stageWidth is 570, and not 640 in the __constructor. Where i can safely start picking actual stage.stageWidth and BE sure that it's the same as i have provided in embed container?

Comment: It's probably that your swf is 570 wide. Normally, it is best that the swf is the same size as it is displayed (as specified in the embed in this case), but if that is not an option, you can set stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE, and stage.stageWidth should then be 640 in the constructor. You may also need to set stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT, to have things aligned correctly.

Comment: Yeah, guess i have placed stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE after stage.stageWidth calculation, that makes sense why it's been 570 and not 640 as it should be. I'll check it.

Comment: Yea, that was the reason. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is about making your flash full screened, then just add this code:

```
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```